# What was the last personal computer to have the chips neatly arranged in rows and columns?

Tags: history, hardware, design-choices

Once upon a time, the chips on the circuit boards of personal computers<sup>1</sup> were arranged in a tidy grid pattern.  Observe the board of the Apple ][+:

[image: Apple II+ motherboard]

Or the Commodore 128:

[image: C128 motherboard]

Sadly, the zen of neat rows and columns of chips is no longer practiced.  This can be attributed to several factors:

- The overall shape of boards are now designed to efficiently fit around other computer components.  Rectangular boards are rare, custom shapes are common.
- More transistors per chip has allowed features to be integrated into fewer chips.
- Chip packaging has changed from dual inline packages, to quad packs and pin/ball arrays.
- Board layout is now automated, multilayer, and optimized to reduce board size.
- Grids make it easier for humans to place and repair parts.  Robots now do the former, and the latter is rarely done anymore.

**What was the last personal computer to arrange most<sup>2</sup> of its chips in rows and columns<sup>3</sup>?**

---

<sup>1</sup> "Personal computer" in the general sense of something that might be used at home or in a small business; not the specific sense of the IBM PC or its clones.

It's likely that supercomputers and other rackmounted stuff still have boards with a grid arrangement, but such items are outside the scope of this question.  Laptops are okay (but were particularly under pressure to have custom-shaped boards).

<sup>2</sup> "Most" means more than half of the board's chips.  See the C128 example above.

<sup>3</sup> You need at least 3 chips in a straight line to make a proper row (or column).  So the minimum arrangement is 3 rows by 3 columns.  Minor repositioning due to different size chips is acceptable.

Comment: “Rectangular boards are rare, custom shapes are common.” — cue me, scratching my head as I consider all the ATX etc. boards on the market... SSD PCBs with flash chips in grids don’t match the requirements, but are perhaps the example most people are at all likely to encounter nowadays.

Comment: Not sure if that is a proper question, as it carries a lot of assumptions to make a point that is more of aesthetic concerns then anything else, as this is abotu the design/layout process, not any technical reasoning.

Comment: (Sorry, no time to write an answer, rushed, but) Fewer ICs holding typical system's memory, large no. of ICs makes a slower memory array at today's speeds, DIL packages lent themselves to such track patterns where BGAs don't, engineers then didn't have cheap access to eCAD software that lets you place chips 'untidily' while getting controlled impedances so they couldn't readily experiment with alternative layouts. And so on.

Comment: It was never about the nodes (e.g. chips). It was always about the network (e.g. connections). Those orientations are due to those rectangular chips aligned to those parallel buses. Changing one changes all, and you might as well ask why layouts with square chips don't always put pin #1 in the upper-left orientation.

Answer (score 7):

Large grids of chips in micro-computers are usually memory chips, and they disappeared from motherboards as memory density increased, and then moved to SIMMs. So large grids were a common sight on 8-bit micros, less so on 16/32-bit micros: for example [early Atari STs](https://temlib.org/AtariForumWiki/index.php/Atari_ST_motherboard_revisions) had memory chips on their motherboards, in smaller grids, but later models used SIMMs.

I suspect the last personal computer motherboards to feature grids of chips were either late-stage 286 or 386 motherboards with on-board memory such as [this monstrous DTK 386 motherboard from 1990](http://www.redhill.net.au/b/b-92.html#dtk-cache386):

[image: DTK 386 motherboard]

or (if they have enough chips to qualify), cache-equipped 486 motherboards such as [the PX486P3](http://www.redhill.net.au/b/b-94.html#px486p3) from 1994:

[image: PX486P3 motherboard]

Answer (score 6):

### TL;DR

It's still done in today's PCs ... as long as there are still chips to be ordered.

---

### Cases

While ordering chips neatly in rows and column is for most parts an aesthetic issue, it never vanished as such. What happened is that chips first shrunk down in size, when SMD became a thing, and second as became more integrated, producing square blobs with a lot of connections that need space to be routed, leaving fewer and fewer chips to build orderly rows and columns.

While the organisation is easy to see on early 90s boards, like [shown by Stephen Kitt](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/18329/6659), it was still there in the late 90s, like this 1996 Pentium Pro board shows:

[image]

Chips are still ordered in an upright fashion, except there are only a few left beside high integrated ones, all filling the upper right corner - with most of them turned into SMD.

Today's boards, like this AMD EPYC board have their few remaining components as well ordered nicely in rows and columns. It's simply less visible among all those connectors.

[image]

Back in the 80s chips counted for the majority of board space - now connectors rule the space and chips have become a few, placed inbetween.

That's BTW the reason why I used top end boards as example, as they are the only ones with a notable number of separate chips left. Low end boards, like this AMD RYZEN - which is essentially the same technology level than the above EPYC - feature next no no other chips beside the CPU-SoC:

[image]

Here is nothing left to be put up in a grid. Everything is within the CPU-SoC. The board doesn't hold much components beside that and power supply regulation. It's main meaning is to distribute the many contacts of the CPU-SoC to all the various connectors and interfaces. Heck, even the so called chipset, here hidden beneath fan cover in the lower right, is in low end versions simply an interface demultiplexer, as the CPU doesn't feature enough pins in parallel to provide all lines, despite having 1331 pins (falling short of 1337 :))

---

### Bottom Line

Orderly placement is still something designers do, hard to see with less and less chips.

Comment: I stopped when 3×3 grids disappeared ;-).

Comment: @StephenKitt No argument :) I just tried to make a point that there never has been a move away from 'orderly' placement. Much the same way we never moved away from cleaning streets from horse .. err ... tracees. There are simply no many horsed left in major cities :)) (Unless it's Oktoberfest)

Comment: @Raffzahn Could you be persuaded to change phrasing to "fewer and fewer chips", given that chips are countable?

Comment: @njuffa Huh? Err ... sure.

Comment: @Raffzahn It simply jumped out at me at the end of this fine answer. For a humorous take on the issue, check out Al Yankovic's song "Word Crimes" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Gv0H-vPoDc), at the one-minute mark.

Comment: @Raffzahn indeed!

Answer (score 1):

Apple Mac Mini M1 2021 - Not many chips on there, but the ones that are present are nicely arranged

[image]

So, I guess your observation is wrong.

Comment: That's the thing: the grid of rows and columns looks much less impressive when you have only a handful of chips to arrange. But that doesn't make it less of a grid.